# angular.js Regular Expression examples? How to use with angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, angularjs

I have scope.data which has inside array questions

questions: [{q1:sth1,q2:sth1,q3:sth2},{q1:sth2,q2:sth1,q3:sth2}...]

I want to use angular.forEach expression to iterate through array and for each q[1-9] count how many it has vaules sth1 and sth2

In example bellow result would be q1:sth1 = 1, q1:sth2 = 1, q2:sth1 = 2, q2:sth2 = 0, etc....

actually i don't know how to use regular expression.

For example

angular.forEach(array.questions.q/[0-9]/  ?? So it will make some business logic for each value q1 q2 q3 q4, depending on case how many of them i will have in array's objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  {q1:sth1,q2:sth1,q3:sth2},
  {q1:sth2,q2:sth1,q3:sth2},
  {q1:sth2,q2:sth1,q3:sth1}
];

var count = {};
angular.forEach($scope.data, function (question, key) {
    var context = this;
    Object.keys(question).forEach( function (prop) {
      if (prop.search(/q[1-9]/) !== -1 ) {
        var value = question[prop];
        if (context[prop] === undefined) {
          context[prop] = {};
          context[prop][value] = 1;        
        } else if (context[prop][value] === undefined) { 
          context[prop][value] = 1;
        } else {
          context[prop][value]++;          
        }
      }
    });
}, count);
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ptZ0ts9Au07derVlCiqt?p=preview)